# Make Sure All Printf's in a Thread Actually Print

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix, printf

I'm running a highly threaded application (500+ threads).  I need to trace some data from them, and to do so I was printing from the thread.  The output is only cut off it seems.  I've also made sure to flush stdout often and I've also tried using a mutex to coordinate output.  None of those solutions have worked.

This is the thread in question:

```
void* troutine(void* tmp) {
    a = RDTSC();
    chance = Park(state);
    b = RDTSC();

    printf("%s.%i.%c : %lli\n", IMPLEMENTATION, *(int*)tmp, 'T', b-a);


    usleep(RAND(50));

    a = RDTSC();
    Leave(chance, state);
    b = RDTSC();
    printf("%s.%i.%c : %lli\n", IMPLEMENTATION, *(int*)tmp, 'T', b-a);

    fflush(stdout);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Only about half the print statements actually print, which is the problem.  I need to make sure they all print, the order doesn't matter, and none of the output is interweaved.

**EDIT** main.c

```
for(i = 0; i < 4000; i++) 
    while(!pthread_create(&tmp, NULL, &troutine, (void*)&testNum));
```

The while loop is so that I ensure the creation of 4k threads as sometimes pthread_create fails with so many threads active.  Also, even when I only set the loop to make i < 4 threads, I still get ~300 lines of output (as opposed to 8).

Comment: See Duck's answer. It covers both of your problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) You will fall out of main() before your threads finish.  Either join the threads or put a pthread_exit() in main() so it doesn't kill your running threads when it exits.

```
for(i = 0; i < 4000; i++) 
    while(!pthread_create(&tmp, NULL, &troutine, (void*)&testNum));
```

(2) Pthread_create returns 0 on success.  So the above while loop is saying "while successful, keep creating threads".  That would explain so much output when i is only 4.

Comment: You hit both problems exactly. The easiest fix to OP's code would be to remove the `!` in that `while` loop and add `pthread_exit(0)` to the end of `main`.

Answer (score 1):

Edit 2: Another possibility is that your problem is outside of this code and that something is calling `exit` (if not crashing) so that half of your threads never finish.  It would really help to know more about what you mean by "cut-off".

---

[As R mentions, this shouldn't be necessary.  Only leaving it so the comment thread makes sense.]

When you say you're using a lock, are you using some kind of global mutex like:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
printf("%s.%i.%c : %lli\n", IMPLEMENTATION, *(int*)tmp, 'T', b-a);
pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);
```

because I don't see that in your example.  Note that `mutex` needs to be defined in the above example, and also needs to be a pointer.

Comment: I have the feeling you should also `fflush` inside the mutex lock, but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: I've done a lot of logging in multithreaded apps without any fflush calls, but my threads always gracefully exit if things are working as designed.  The fflush calls will result in a lot of delays, more so if done within the lock.  The main thing I'm trying to avoid are two simultaneous calls to printf since I haven't checked if it's thread safe.

Comment: @B Mitch - Yeah. It was an initial instinct, after which I realized that locking for the stream writes was sufficient. However, it's possible that you should lock for the final call to `fflush`, or perhaps `fflush` in main after all the other threads finish.

Comment: @B Mitch, I did try to do exactly that, with a global mutex.  It didn't help.  However, if I create a thread and then join it (from the main thread) such that each thread goes one a time; everything works.

Comment: @Lanissum - are you sure you aren't dropping out of main() and ending the program before you think?

Comment: I shouldn't be, but I'll post the relevant part of main.

Comment: None of this is needed. POSIX requires stdio `FILE`s to have a builtin mutex or equivalent. I'll hold off on downvoting, but this answer is wrong as stated and advising adding wasteful secondary locking.

Comment: @R: Good to know. The reason for my locking is as I said, because I haven't independently verified that it's thread safe everywhere I'll use this. My standard method when programming in threaded programs is to lock everything I'm not sure of and only remove the lock when I double check the manual. It looks like "edit 2" is the answer, but at the time that was just a guess because we didn't have the main.c posted yet.